# font-size in the whole application

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails, fonts

i have huge application running in Ruby On Rails.And now i want to decrease fonts to some pixels. its not possible for me to find out in the whole app that where font-size have been used.

is there any way to fix this for whole application at once that if fonts are

```
font-size: 23px
font-size: 10px
```

and with CSS or jquery, i may decrease font-size at once and this will become

```
font-size: 20px
font-size: 7px
```

if i decreased it to 3 pixels for whole application.. supposing that all font sizes are in different files. but as we can hit everyfile by `application.css` or `application.js` in rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like `em` or `rem` (root `em`). So your code will be like:

```css
body {font-size: 10pt;}

p {font-size: 1.2em;}
h1 {font-size: 1.5em;}
```

Note the `em` based values. You can just use body's value to increase or decrease the `font-size` proportionally.

```css
body.inc50percent {font-size: 1.5em;}
```

**Working Snippet**

```js
$(function () {
  $("a").click(function () {
    $("body").removeClass("inc25percent inc50percent inc75percent").addClass($(this).data("class"));
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
body {font-size: 10pt;}

p {font-size: 1.2em;}
h1 {font-size: 1.5em;}

body.inc25percent {font-size: 1.25em;}
body.inc50percent {font-size: 1.5em;}
body.inc75percent {font-size: 1.75em;}

.action,
.action p,
.action a {font-size: 10pt; line-height: 1em; margin: 0 0 5px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="action">
  <p>Choose the font size. Whatever you choose, these remain the same.</p>
  <a href="#" data-class="nothing">Reset</a>
  <a href="#" data-class="inc25percent">Increase 25%</a>
  <a href="#" data-class="inc50percent">Increase 50%</a>
  <a href="#" data-class="inc75percent">Increase 75%</a>
</div>

<h1>Hello</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum voluptatum magnam a dolore, nesciunt nemo modi, quaerat aliquid delectus fugit optio sit, officia ab quidem eum consequatur quam expedita. Nemo.</p>
<p>Nemo aut, iure amet laboriosam eaque atque non quam. Ab nihil voluptatem suscipit dicta mollitia eaque dolor saepe error qui, voluptas consequatur odit voluptatum deleniti porro sequi, libero, sunt reiciendis.</p>
<p>Nemo omnis possimus animi at magnam consequuntur neque? Ad similique possimus nobis id rem, sapiente neque aliquam iure, nisi nemo at excepturi asperiores facilis recusandae aperiam nostrum itaque consequatur. Eum.</p>
<p>Voluptates dolorem quia nemo fugit aperiam labore fuga. At quo ex numquam facere? Dolores facere quisquam perferendis aut voluptatibus, asperiores ducimus provident obcaecati ea ipsam. Sequi quisquam perferendis animi labore.</p>
<p>Ut, adipisci est vel nulla totam quas voluptate, officia maxime, cumque, cum rerum delectus pariatur. Aut exercitationem, eum illum nobis molestias natus esse libero placeat eligendi hic, inventore nisi maxime.</p>
```

**Update:** Added non-changing constant font sized elements.

Comment: it will work ? i dont think so. U didnt understand my question

Comment: @JunaidFarooq You need to change all the font-sizes to use relative font-sizes, instead of pixel based ones.

Comment: i just want to decrease fonts in whole application.
font-size: 78px somewhere
font-size: 12px somewhere and on one change
70px
2px.

Comment: @JunaidFarooq Check and tell if this is what you are looking for: http://output.jsbin.com/favosinapa

Comment: @JunaidFarooq I have added snippet also. Check if that's what you are expecting. See that both the paragraph's and heading's height change proportionally.

Comment: yess am looking for this but in decrement + in example all stable font sizes are same. in my condition they can be different as 10px and 20px then can i decrease it to 8 and 18 px?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100384/discussion-between-praveen-kumar-and-junaid-farooq).

Comment: @JunaidFarooq Click on the above link and come to chat buddy. `:)`

Comment: @JunaidFarooq See the updated snippet for constant, non-changing font-size elements too.